# Generate “never-expire” access token for Facebook

Tags: php

I have this error 
"(OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: The session is invalid

How do I generate access token which is never expired?

I use this code:

```
<?php
    require 'facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => ' ',
        'secret' => ' ',
        'cookie' => true
    ));
    $fbPageID = $_GET['url'];
    $token = " ";
    $facebook->setAccessToken($token);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user){
        $json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbPageID . '/subscribers?access_token='.$token);
        $data = json_decode($json);
        echo  $data->summary->total_count;
    }else{
        echo "token non valido.";
        /*
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl()."&scope=offline_access,manage_pages";
        header("location:".$loginurl);
        exit();
        */
    }
    ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The main property of an access token is that it is a temporary token which will expire after some time. I don't think it is possible to generate a access token which is always valid. Thats the nature of a token for security reasons.

Comment: @steven  ok.. but something is changed? because this my code is not working anymore..

Comment: It sounds like what has changed is that the token has expired. You need to build into your application the logic for requesting a new one.

Comment: @IMSoP I change the token and is not working